# Magento 2: changes made on one store must be apply to default store too

Tags: magento2, store-view, media-images, gallery-image

When you edit a product on the **All Store View** scope it applies the changes to all the stores. I want the reverse of it like if I made changes to a different store then that change must be applied to default or all stores. i.e if I disable an image for **store 1** it should be must be disabled for every **other store** too.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on the scope of an attribute. If an attribute's scope is global, and you change the value of an attribute in any store, then that change will be applied globally, i.e. to all the other stores.

You can change the scope of an attribute to global in Stores -> Attributes -> Select an attribute -> Open the attribute -> Advanced Attribute Properties

If we consider image attribute, I think it is set to store view scope by default. You can try changing it to global scope and it should work.